# How to delete keys in JSON column of MySQL

Tags: mysql, json, json-remove

My data is dirty, and now I am trying to correct them.

The data is like:

```
mysql> select attrs from goods  limit 10;
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| attrs                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| {"logo": "1", "cover": "", "level": 0, "tag_6": 8, "summary": "L1", "showStatus": 0, "classAmount": 0, "productType": 0, "courseEndTime": 1532572800000, "courseStartTime": 1531706400000}  |
| {"logo": "1", "cover": "", "level": 0, "tag_6": 8, "summary": "L1", "showStatus": 0, "classAmount": 0, "productType": 0, "courseEndTime": 1533717600000, "courseStartTime": 1532851200000}  |
| {"logo": "1", "cover": "", "level": 0, "tag_6": 8, "summary": "L1", "showStatus": 0, "classAmount": 0, "productType": 0, "courseEndTime": 1534851600000, "courseStartTime": 1533985200000}  |
| {"logo": "1", "cover": "", "level": 0, "tag_6": 8, "summary": "L2", "showStatus": 0, "classAmount": 0, "productType": 0, "courseEndTime": 1532594400000, "courseStartTime": 1531728000000}  |
| {"logo": "1", "cover": "", "level": 0, "tag_147": 8, "tag_145": 2 "summary": "L2", "showStatus": 0, "classAmount": 0, "productType": 0, "courseEndTime": 1533728400000, "courseStartTime": 1532862000000}  |
| {"logo": "1", "cover": "", "level": 0, "tag_6": 8, "summary": "L2", "showStatus": 0, "classAmount": 0, "productType": 0, "courseEndTime": 1534819200000, "courseStartTime": 1533952800000}  |
| {"logo": "1", "cover": "", "level": 0, "tag_127": 8, "summary": "NGL", "showStatus": 0, "classAmount": 0, "productType": 0, "courseEndTime": 1532605200000, "courseStartTime": 1531738800000} |
| {"logo": "1", "cover": "", "level": 0, "tag_6": 8, "summary": "NGL", "showStatus": 0, "classAmount": 0, "productType": 0, "courseEndTime": 1533696000000, "courseStartTime": 1532829600000} |
|
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

What I want to remove some `(key, value)` pairs in the column `attrs` if any of these pairs exists. 
For example `tag_147` and `tag_124` are dirty, then any hit pair would be removed.

```
{"tag_147": 1, "tag_124": 2}  ===>  {}
{"tag_147": 1 "tag_100":2}  ==>  {"tag_100": 2}
```

How can i achieve it? Thanks.

What I have tried is
1. find `attrs` that contains keys `tag_147` and `tag_124`. 
2. Then update attrs. 
My original Sql is like:

```
update goods
set json_remove(*XXX*) 
where (select json_keys(attrs) from goods ) contains  (*tag_147*, *tag_127*)
```

Here I was blocked by constructing the `contains`  statement...

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to delete those two tags from the `attrs` values that contain *both* of them, you can use `JSON_REMOVE` on any `attrs` values found by `JSON_CONTAINS_PATH`, using the `all` mode of `JSON_CONTAINS_PATH` to only find values which contain *both* tags:

```
UPDATE goods
SET attrs = JSON_REMOVE(attrs, '$.tag_147', '$.tag_124')
WHERE JSON_CONTAINS_PATH(attrs, 'all', '$.tag_147', '$.tag_124')
```

If you want to completely remove rows where the `attrs` values contains both tags, you can use the same `JSON_CONTAINS_PATH` condition in a `DELETE` query:

```
DELETE
FROM goods
WHERE JSON_CONTAINS_PATH(attrs, 'all', '$.tag_147', '$.tag_124')
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=0333247f1b8c89ff6627b8571f85c234)

If you want to delete those tags from the `attrs` values that contain *any* of them, you can remove the `WHERE` clause in the `UPDATE` i.e.

```
UPDATE goods
SET attrs = JSON_REMOVE(attrs, '$.tag_147', '$.tag_145')
```

And to delete rows with `attrs` values containing any of the tags, change the `all` parameter to `JSON_CONTAINS_PATH` to `one`:

```
DELETE
FROM goods
WHERE JSON_CONTAINS_PATH(attrs, 'one', '$.tag_147', '$.tag_145')
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=954d6e1892f5be5674f54a700d2f29f8)

Comment: @Akina without the `WHERE` the `UPDATE` will remove those tags from values which only have one of them instead of both.  See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=79e8a3d66f34beb76065bc39a6f9eb84

Comment: @Akina of course that might be what OP wants... I'll add as an edit

Comment: @Akina I was basing the answer on `then pairs with both keys should all be removed` but the question is unclear, which is why I have edited the answer to include the alternate interpretation

Comment: @shijiexu the second `UPDATE` query in my answer will do what you want. `JSON_REMOVE` will only remove the pairs if they actually exist, so you don't need the `WHERE` clause on the `UPDATE` query. See the second demo link...